# How I can extract a subterm from a term in Prolog?

Tags: tree, prolog, extract

How I can extract a subterm from a term in Prolog?

An example, I am trying to extract a predicate called **r** wherever it is but I do know how. Any help?

term_extraxtions(**s(n(1),t(3,4,r(2,4)))**,ModifiedTerm,ExtractedTerm) 
will be as follows.

ModifiedTerm = **s(n(1),t(3,4))**.

ExtractedTerm = **r(2,4)**.

Comment: What would you want the results to be for, `s(n(1), t(3,r(1,2)), r(3))`? What about, `r(1,2)`? What about `s(n(1), t(r(1,r(2))))`?

Comment: Hi Lurkaer and repeat!  Sure, I want it to fix some parse trees that generated from a wide coverage parser. And about r(1,2) is fine but r(1,r(2)) is not because the parser, that I use,  does not give r predicate inside each other; however it could be next to each other. e,g: s(n(1), r(1,3),r(4,6,7)). I hope now it is clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy manipulation of terms derive from the uniform, recursive definition.
So, let's first 'extract' an argument from a compound:

```
exterm(T, M, E) :-
    T =.. [F|As],
    select(E, As, Bs),
    M =.. [F|Bs].
```

This predicate does most of the work:

```
?- exterm(a(1,b(u)),M,E).
M = a(b(u)),
E = 1 ;
M = a(1),
E = b(u) ;
M = a(1, b),
E = u ;
false.
```

To generalize and complete your assignment, you must allow to *recurse* on each argument, modify it extracting an element, and recompose the argument list.

```
...
append(X, [Y|Ys], As),
... % recursive call
append(X, [Z|Ys], Bs),
...
```

See if you can complete it:

```
?- exterm(s(n(1),t(3,4,r(2,4))),ModifiedTerm,ExtractedTerm), ExtractedTerm=r(_,_).
ModifiedTerm = s(n(1), t(3, 4)),
ExtractedTerm = r(2, 4) ;
false.
```

Here I've constrained the extracted term to match what you show in the question, otherwise there would be a long list of solutions to display...

Comment: Thanks CapelliC. That's will  really help but can I ask if it can extract multiple r predicates or just the first one? Secondly, can you write the second part in more details? because I don't know where I can fit  the exterm(T, M, E) rule.